# How can I find count of capital letter, small letters and words in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to read a text file and find the number of capital letters, small letters and the number of words.

How can I do it?

EDIT

```
main :- write('Acmak istediginiz dosyanin konumunu giriniz...'),nl,
  read(File),nl, 
  open(File,read,InputStream), 
  get_code(InputStream,CharacterCode), 
  LowerCount is 0,
  UpperCount is 0,
  NumberCount is 0,
  SpaceCount is 0,
  WordCount is 0, 
  processChar(CharacterCode,_,InputStream,LowerCount,UpperCoun‌t,NumberCount,SpaceC‌​ount,WordCount), 
  close(InputStream). 

isLower(CharacterCode,C1,C2) :- 
  CharacterCode >= 97,
  CharacterCode =< 122,
  C1 is C2 + 1
  ; 
  C1 is C2. 

isUpper(CharacterCode,C1,C2) :- 
  CharacterCode >= 65,
  CharacterCode =< 90,
  C1 is C2 + 1
  ; 
  C1 is C2. 

isNumber(CharacterCode,C1,C2) :- 
  CharacterCode >= 48,
  CharacterCode =< 57,
  C1 is C2 + 1
  ; 
  C1 is C2. 

isSpace(CharacterCode,C1,C2) :- 
  CharacterCode >= 1,
  CharacterCode =< 32,
  C1 is C2 + 1
  ; 
  C1 is C2.

isWord(CharacterCode,NextCharacterCode,C1,C2) :- 
  CharacterCode >= 0,
  CharacterCode =< 38,
  C1 is C2
  ; 
  CharacterCode >= 40,
  CharacterCode =< 47,
  C1 is C2
  ; 
  CharacterCode >= 58,
  CharacterCode =< 64,
  C1 is C2
  ; 
  CharacterCode >= 91,
  CharacterCode =< 96,
  C1 is C2
  ; 
  CharacterCode >= 123,
  C1 is C2
  ; 
  NextCharacterCode >= 48,
  NextCharacterCode =< 57,
  C1 is C2
  ; 
  NextCharacterCode =:= 39,
  C1 is C2
  ; 
  NextCharacterCode >= 65,
  NextCharacterCode =< 90,
  C1 is C2
  ; 
  NextCharacterCode >= 97,
  NextCharacterCode =< 122,
  C1 is C2
  ; 
  C1 is C2+1. 

processChar(-1,[],_,LowerCount,UpperCount,NumberCount,SpaceC‌​ount,WordCount) :- 
  write('Harf Sayisi = '), LetterCount is LowerCount + UpperCount, write(LetterCount),nl, 
  write('Kucuk Harf Sayisi = '), write(LowerCount), nl,
  write('Buyuk Harf Sayisi = '), write(UpperCount), nl, 
  write('Rakam Sayisi = '), write(NumberCount), nl, 
  write('Boşluk Sayisi = '), write(SpaceCount), nl, 
  write('Kelime Sayisi = '), write(WordCount), nl, !. 

processChar(CharacterCode,[CharacterCode|CharacterCodes],Inp‌​utStream,LowerCount,‌​UpperCount,NumberCou‌​nt,SpaceCount,WordCo‌​unt) :- 
  isUpper(CharacterCode,UpperCount1,UpperCount), 
  isLower(CharacterCode,LowerCount1,LowerCount), 
  isNumber(CharacterCode,NumberCount1,NumberCount), 
  isSpace(CharacterCode,SpaceCount1,SpaceCount), 
  get_code(InputStream,NextCharacterCode), 
  isWord(CharacterCode,NextCharacterCode,WordCount1,WordCount‌​), 
  processChar(NextCharacterCode,CharacterCodes,InputStream,Low‌erCount1,UpperCount1‌​,NumberCount1,SpaceC‌​ount1,WordCount1).
```

Comment: What's your specific problem? e.g. Are you getting a compiler or runtime error. What have you tried? e.g. Show your Prolog code.  Have you taken the [tour] and read [ask]?

Comment: I tried to open and read  file with open('c:/Users/Me/Desktop/test.txt', read, Str) function and did it but i could not get all of the text and could not find that the latter is capital or not.

Comment: Can you post `test.txt` here. I take it that it is less than 20 lines. Also try and write some Prolog rules that don't read input from a file and see if you can figure out how to identify the capital and small letters. If you get stuck on one part of the problem break the problem down into smaller parts and work on the other parts. You should also post that code here and show if you have that working or what the additional problem. In short don't expect an answer unless you show your work. This sounds like homework.

Comment: Yes true it is my part of homework.I m trying to read my test file and get char.I could read file with function i said but it read from point to point.İf i can take all the test.txt i will take the characters in order and look it is big or small.The index of my test.txt is; "GryFfindor.. HuffLepufF. 
ravenclaW .
slytheriN." also thx for the advice I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code using SWI-Prolog on Windows 10.
Not all of the solution is here as this is homework I left that up to you, but I did verify that the all of these parts work together.

### Reading a file

I noticed you referenced [Learn Prolog Now! - 12.3 Reading from Files](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse54) in a comment. I too found that page to be a bit confusing.

```erlang
processChar(end_of_file,[],_) :- !.  % EOF

processChar(CharacterCode,[CharacterCode|CharacterCodes],InputStream) :-
    get_code(InputStream,NextCharacterCode),
    processChar(NextCharacterCode,CharacterCodes,InputStream).

main :-
    open('C:/Users/Eric/Documents/Prolog/test.txt',read,InputStream),
    get_code(InputStream,CharacterCode),
    processChar(CharacterCode,CharacterCodes,InputStream),
    write(CharacterCodes), nl,
    string_codes(Characters,CharacterCodes),
    write(Characters), nl,
    close(InputStream).
```

When run

```erlang
main.
[71,114,121,70,102,105,110,100,111,114,46,10,72,117,102,102,76,101,112,117,102,70,46,10,114,97,118,101,110,99,108,97,87,46,10,115,108,121,116,104,101,114,105,78,46]
GryFfindor.
HuffLepufF.
ravenclaW.
slytheriN.
true.
```

### Checking specific character types

Since Prolog works with character codes instead of characters here is a hint to find lower case characters, with the input being ASCII character codes.

```erlang
isLower(CharacterCode) :-
    CharacterCode >= 97,
    CharacterCode =< 122.
```

### Counting words

One way to count the words is to pass two state variables around. One gets modified as the characters are processed, and the second is used to pass back the final answer.

When you hit a condition that ends a word such as a space, end of line, or end of file, you increment the count.

```erlang
processChar(...,WordCount,WordCount2) :-
    ...
    WordCount1 is WordCount + 1,
    processChar(...,WordCount1,WordCount2).
```

Otherwise you just pass the values on for the characters in a word.

```erlang
processChar(...,WordCount,WordCount2) :-
    ...
    processChar(...,WordCount,WordCount2).
```

When you reach the end of the input, e.g. `-1`, you move the count into the other variable that will be used for the output.

```erlang
processChar(-1, ... ,WordCount,WordCount1) :-
    WordCount1 is WordCount + 1.
```

Add initialize the count in the main, e.g. `0`.

```erlang
main :-
    ...
    processChar(...,0,WordCount),
    write(WordCount), nl,
    ... .
```

There are many other ways to do this with Prolog and more idomatic, but this should get you started.

Comment: I did it with the informatio you give.Thank you very much.for the help Guy Coder.Im adding homework.Good Night....
`main :-
 write('Acmak istediginiz dosyanin konumunu giriniz...'),nl,
 read(File),nl,
        open(File,read,InputStream),
        get_code(InputStream,CharacterCode),
        LowerCount is 0,UpperCount is 0,NumberCount is 0,SpaceCount is 0,WordCount is 0,
        processChar(CharacterCode,_,InputStream,LowerCount,UpperCount,NumberCount,SpaceCount,WordCount),
        close(InputStream).`

Comment: `isLower(CharacterCode,C1,C2) :-
        CharacterCode >= 97,CharacterCode =< 122,C1 is C2 + 1;
 C1 is C2.`                                                 `isUpper(CharacterCode,C1,C2) :-
        CharacterCode >= 65,CharacterCode =< 90,C1 is C2 + 1;
 C1 is C2.`                                                `isNumber(CharacterCode,C1,C2) :-
        CharacterCode >= 48,CharacterCode =< 57,C1 is C2 + 1;
 C1 is C2.`                                                 `isSpace(CharacterCode,C1,C2) :-
        CharacterCode >= 1,CharacterCode =< 32,C1 is C2 + 1;
 C1 is C2.`

Comment: `isWord(CharacterCode,NextCharacterCode,C1,C2) :-
 CharacterCode >= 0,CharacterCode =< 38,C1 is C2;
 CharacterCode >= 40,CharacterCode =< 47,C1 is C2;
 CharacterCode >= 58,CharacterCode =< 64,C1 is C2;
 CharacterCode >= 91,CharacterCode =< 96,C1 is C2;
 CharacterCode >= 123,C1 is C2;
        NextCharacterCode >= 48,NextCharacterCode =< 57,C1 is C2;
 NextCharacterCode =:= 39,C1 is C2;
        NextCharacterCode >= 65,NextCharacterCode =< 90,C1 is C2;
        NextCharacterCode >= 97,NextCharacterCode =< 122,C1 is C2;
 C1 is C2+1.`

Comment: `processChar(-1,[],_,LowerCount,UpperCount,NumberCount,SpaceCount,WordCount):-
 write('Harf Sayisi = '),LetterCount is LowerCount + UpperCount,write(LetterCount),nl,
 write('Kucuk Harf Sayisi = '),write(LowerCount),nl,
 write('Buyuk Harf Sayisi = '),write(UpperCount),nl,
 write('Rakam Sayisi = '),write(NumberCount),nl,
 write('Boşluk Sayisi = '),write(SpaceCount),nl,
 write('Kelime Sayisi = '),write(WordCount),nl,
 !.`

Comment: `processChar(CharacterCode,[CharacterCode|CharacterCodes],InputStream,LowerCount,UpperCount,NumberCount,SpaceCount,WordCount) :-
 isUpper(CharacterCode,UpperCount1,UpperCount),
        isLower(CharacterCode,LowerCount1,LowerCount),
 isNumber(CharacterCode,NumberCount1,NumberCount),
 isSpace(CharacterCode,SpaceCount1,SpaceCount),
 get_code(InputStream,NextCharacterCode),
 isWord(CharacterCode,NextCharacterCode,WordCount1,WordCount),
        processChar(NextCharacterCode,CharacterCodes,InputStream,LowerCount1,UpperCount1,NumberCount1,SpaceCount1,WordCount1).`

Comment: I sent a little complicated and contents of write is Turkish.Im sorry for that :(.